# How to Exclude Semicolons from MSBuild ExtensionPack.FileSystem.File Replacements

Tags: regex, replace, msbuild, msbuildextensionpack

I'm using MSBuild extension pack to replace lines in .proj files.
I'm replacing multiple lines with multiple lines. The lines it's outputting still have a semi colon at the end even when I do a transform.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <TestFile Include="regextest.xml" />
    <MyLines Include ="%3CItemGroup%3E%0A"/>
    <MyLines Include ="%09%3CReference Include=%22Stuff%22%3E%0A" />
    <MyLines Include ="%09%09%3CHintPath%3E..\..\packages\secret.dll%3C/HintPath%3E%0A" />
    <MyLines Include ="%09%09%3CPrivate%3ETrue%3C/Private%3E%0A" />
    <MyLines Include ="%09%3C/Reference%3E%0A" />
    <MyLines Include ="%3C/ItemGroup%3E%0A" />
</ItemGroup>


<Target Name="Default">
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.File TaskAction="Replace" 
      TextEncoding="ASCII" 
      RegexPattern="%3CProjectReference"
      RegexOptionList="IgnoreCase"
      Replacement="@(MyLines->'%(Identity)')"
      Files="@(TestFile)" />
</Target>
```

And this is the output:

```
<ItemGroup>
;   <Reference Include="Stuff">
;       <HintPath>..\..\packages\secret.dll</HintPath>
;       <Private>True</Private>
;   </Reference>
;</ItemGroup>
```

Doing it without the transform still has them there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to handle multi-line replacement strings is to form them in a `CDATA` block inside of a property instead of a collection of single-line items (this is where the semicolons come from). In this case, you could create the multi-line replacement string as a property and then assign its value to an item, then pass the item to the `Replace` task action:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <MyMultiLine>
  <![CDATA[
  %3CItemGroup%3E
    %3CReference Include="Stuff"%3E
      %3CHintPath%3E..\..\packages\secret.dll%3C/HintPath%3E
      %3CPrivate>True%3C/Private%3E
    %3C/Reference%3E
  %3C/ItemGroup%3E
  ]]>
  </MyMultiLine>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <TestFile Include="regextest.xml" />
  <MyMultiLineItem Include="$(MyMultiLine)" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="Default">
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.File TaskAction="Replace" 
      TextEncoding="ASCII" 
      RegexPattern="%3CProjectReference"
      RegexOptionList="IgnoreCase"
      Replacement="@(MyMultiLineItem ->'%(Identity)')"
      Files="@(TestFile)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: works wonderfully! thank you very much!  Now I just need to figure out how to capture from <projectreference> to </projectreference> and I'll be in good shape!

Comment: I got it - RegexPattern="(%3CProjectReference)(.*\n){4}(.*ProjectReference%3E)"  The 4 new lines are for my particular case, but this may help someone else..